# How to let User A write blog posts for Blog A, but not Blog B

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm looking for a module/technique that will let me restrict to allow User A to write on Blog A, but not Blog B.  However, User B can write on Blogs A and B, but not C.  Basically, it needs to be flexible...  But, it's proving to be difficult.  Has anyone run into anything like this?  Oh... and it can't use a different role for each one.  All writers share the same role.

My initial thoughts...

- Create a content type named Blog, which contains a User Reference field for those allowed to write to it.
- Create a Blog Post content type that has a Node Reference to the Blogs for which the user is referenced (using a View to select the nodes).

That will make it so User A can write only on Blog A, but it doesn't prevent User A from opening a Blog Post on Blog B and editing it.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to have a look at how http://drupal.org/project/forum_access is handling it. That use case (Only having view, update, and/or create permission for specific forums) sounds very similar to yours. Maybe http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite might even just work, but I'm not sure if you can give users control over the taxonomy that also controls access.

Especially if you also use taxonomy to separate your blogs.

So, you could have a taxonomy that is basically a list of all blogs you have. Then configure which users are allowed to use which terms. When creating content, limit the taxonomy to the terms they have access to (might need some custom code, not sure). Once created, they are only allowed to edit those with the terms they are allowed to "use". That should work out of the box with tac_lite.

Comment: Well, I've played around with the tac_lite, and it looks like it'll help with the edit/delete/view permissions.  But, it doesn't seem to help too much with the creation permissions.  But, I did a quick and dirty custom module to help support that.  So... it appears to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to use an RBAC model to do that, you could just create a table that holds all the permissions and then assign a permission to whoever you think is needed. The permission table can be like :

permissions (id, action)

examples : (1, 'write A'), (2, 'write B') ...

Then you also have a user table of course that specifies your users.

Finally, you create a user_roles table like :

user_roles (user_id, permission_id)

And you can pass any permission to any user you like :) Hope that helps.

EDIT : oops, i've just noticed that this is about drupal. My answer is about database models. Sorry about that.